# Beautiful soup - modify existing HTML content

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add the string `<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>` to each of the rows below in my HTML file after the `<th>` tag.

I'm looking for a generic solution as the WW strings may change. For example WW32 may change to WW58 on the next HTML file generation.

My initial thought was to use beautiful soup but any other solution is welcomed.

Current HTML code:

```
  <th>KEY</th>
  <th>DEVREVSTEP</th>
  <th>WW32</th>
  <th>WW33</th>
  <th>WW34</th>
  <th>WW35</th>
  <th>WW36</th>
  <th>WW37</th>
  <th>WW38</th>
  <th>WW39</th>
  <th>WW40</th>
  <th>Rule</th>
  <th>LINK</th>
```

Desired HTML code:

```
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>KEY</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>DEVREVSTEP</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW32</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW33</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW34</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW35</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW36</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW37</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW38</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW39</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW40</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>Rule</th>
<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>LINK</th>
```

---

Full HTML file code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h2> Title here </h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"><table border="1" class="dataframe wide" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>KEY</th>
      <th>DEVREVSTEP</th>
      <th>WW32</th>
      <th>WW33</th>
      <th>WW34</th>
      <th>WW35</th>
      <th>WW36</th>
      <th>WW37</th>
      <th>WW38</th>
      <th>WW39</th>
      <th>WW40</th>
      <th>Rule</th>
      <th>LINK</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.64</td>
      <td>6.47</td>
      <td>23.14</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.13</td>
      <td>-0.41</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>-0.31</td>
      <td>33.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>-18.04</td>
      <td>-18.42</td>
      <td>-17.44</td>
      <td>-16.35</td>
      <td>-19.06</td>
      <td>-17.49</td>
      <td>-18.62</td>
      <td>-17.92</td>
      <td>-18.23</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Amazon.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>2.25</td>
      <td>-0.33</td>
      <td>0.55</td>
      <td>-0.53</td>
      <td>8.96</td>
      <td>17.53</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Ebay.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Fourth</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.18</td>
      <td>3.25</td>
      <td>7.63</td>
      <td>1.90</td>
      <td>-0.19</td>
      <td>0.41</td>
      <td>0.15</td>
      <td>0.20</td>
      <td>17.31</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>MT6@DCCD@NEST@X-BAR</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
      <td>-3.25</td>
      <td>-6.42</td>
      <td>-1.51</td>
      <td>0.60</td>
      <td>-0.01</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>-0.02</td>
      <td>-15.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>MSN.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>5.06</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>1.27</td>
      <td>-0.56</td>
      <td>13.24</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its can be done without the help of beautiful soup. You just need to read the HTML file as text and use the find and replace function below to write into the file.

```
import fileinput
import sys

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

replaceAll("CDs_Report.html","<th>KEY</th>",'<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>KEY</th>')
replaceAll("CDs_Report.html","<th>DEVREVSTEP</th>",'<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>DEVREVSTEP</th>')
replaceAll("CDs_Report.html","<th>WW",'<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW')
replaceAll("CDs_Report.html","<th>Rule</th>",'<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>Rule</th>')
replaceAll("CDs_Report.html","<th>LINK</th>",'<th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>LINK</th>')
```